# Question regarding Stirling Numbers of the second kind - regarding partitions and recurrences.

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

This question is prefaced by this part:

We use the notation *S(k,n)* to stand for the number of partitions of a *k* element set with *n* blocks. For historical reasons, *S(k,n)* is called a *Stirling Number of the second kind*.

Question:

> In a partition of the set [*k*], the number *k* is either in a block
>   by itself, or it is not. How does the number of partitions of [*k*]
>   with *n* parts in which *k* is in a block with other elements of [*k*]
>   compare to the number of partitions  of [*k - 1*] into *n* blocks?
>   Find a two-variable recurrence for *S(k,n)*, valid for *k* and *n*
>   larger than one.

So if I understand this correctly the answer will be a proof? Can I reach the answer by enumerating different example partitions of sets? I appreciate any tips and help. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer will be a recurrence together with an explanation justifying that recurrence. For example, the binomial coefficients satisfy the two-variable recurrence $$\binom{k}n=\binom{k-1}{n-1}+\binom{k-1}n\tag{1}$$ (which you may recognize as the rule used to form Pascal’s triangle). The Stirling numbers of the second kind, which are also written $$\left\{\matrix{k\\n}\right\}$$ instead of $S(k,n)$, satisfy a two variable recurrence quite similar to $(1)$, though a little more complicated. One term counts the partitions of $[k]$ in which $\{k\}$ is a block by itself; the other counts the partitions of $[k]$ in which $k$ is in a block with something else.

To get you started, if $\{k\}$ is a block by itself, the remaining $k-1$ elements of $[k]$ must make up the other $n-1$ blocks. There are $S(k-1,n-1)$ ways in which they can do this, so there are how many partitions of $[k]$ in which $\{k\}$ is a block by itself?

Comment: Binet's formula, isn't that about Fibonacci numbers? I know this one under the name of Pascal's rule.

Comment: @Marc: My brain evidently went walkabout for a moment. Thanks!

Comment: @Brian, Thank You Very Much! I'm slowly getting it, but still a bit puzzled(just the concept of Stirling #s itself), so I'll have to read more on wikipedia.